# Retrieve a field from the form header of a CRM 2011 form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a custom field on the header of a CRM form. I need to check if it has a value or not and then perform a certain function.

Now, for all fields on the form I can use

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_attributename").getValue();
```

However, for the field in the header that does not seem to work. How can I retrieve the value and check if it is null or has a specific value?

I tried this

```
document.getElementById("header_new_attributename_d");
```

That returned a value but I am stuck with absolutely no clue on how to get the value further?

I tried

```
document.getElementById("header_new_attributename_d").value
```

and that is undefined.

How can I get the value of the field and check if it is null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The supported way is to add the field also to the body of the form and set it to be not visible by default.

In this way you can use the supported method `getValue` and the field is only displayed inside the header.

[image]